# Issues creating table from bucket file

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have a big table (About 10 million rows) that I'm trying to pull into my bigquery. I had to upload the CSV into the bucket due to the size constraints when creating the table. When I try to create the table using the Datastore, the job fails with the error:

```
Error Reason:invalid. Get more information about this error at Troubleshooting Errors: invalid.
Errors:
gs://es_main/provider.csv does not contain valid backup metadata.
Job ID: liquid-cumulus:job_KXxmLZI0Ulch5WmkIthqZ4boGgM
Start Time: Dec 16, 2015, 3:00:51 PM
End Time: Dec 16, 2015, 3:00:51 PM
Destination Table: liquid-cumulus:ES_Main.providercloudtest
Source URI: gs://es_main/provider.csv
Source Format: Datastore Backup
```

I've troubleshot by using a small sample file of rows from the same table and just uploading using the CSV feature in the table creation without any errors and can view the data just fine.

I'm just wondering what the metadata should be set as with the "Edit metadata" option within the bucket or if there is some other work around I'm missing. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message for the job that you posted is telling you that the file you're providing is not a [Datastore Backup file](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/datastoreadmin?hl=en#backup_and_restore_data).  Note that "Datastore" here means [Google Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/overview), which is another storage solution that it sounds like you aren't using.  A Cloud Datastore Backup is a specific file type from that storage product which is different from CSV or JSON.

Setting the file metadata within the Google Cloud Storage browser, which is where the "Edit metadata" option you're talking about lives, should have no impact on how BigQuery imports your file.  It might be important if you were doing something more involved with your file from Cloud Storage, but it isn't important to BigQuery as far as I know.

To upload a CSV file from Google Cloud Storage to BigQuery, make sure to select the CSV source format and the Google Storage load source as pictured below.

[image: Select data step showing how to select CSV format and GCS URI]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm new to Google so I could be missing something, but I'm not using their Datastore to upload the data but the Storage > Buckets. When I upload I'm not given any option as to what type of data I'm uploading, just the "Upload File" with any selection. Once the file is uploaded, there are options to adjust the metadata; this is what it looks like by default: http://postimg.org/image/j436jgm7p/

Comment: I've edited my response above to hopefully clarify.  Short version: "Edit metadata" should have no impact on how BigQuery imports your data.  Make sure to select "CSV" as the source format when uploading a file, or your CSV file will be interpreted as a different data format and fail.